# Moderator messages without suspension don't appear under "Annotations" in the user history

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

The user history (`users/history/[id]`) has a section "Annotations" at the top. There annotations by a moderator appear as well as moderator messages including a suspension.

What doesn't appear there are moderator messages without suspensions, which I would have expected to be included in that section. To see those one still has to look at the full history and look for moderator message entries.

This section should include *all* moderator messages, even those without suspension.

I've omitted a screenshot as I would have had to blank out pretty much the whole page.

Comment: It really isn't shown there? I expected it would be!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We've fixed a couple different things about the whole manner of annotations and the like. For the same reasons as your lack of screenshots, this answer too will lack screenshots.

The top section of the user history page will now contain all manner of contact and annotation. There are three different kinds of "entries" that will show up, which will be noted by the kind of entry and which moderator is responsible for the entry.

- **Annotations** will include the text of the annotation. These you get for your normal annotations.
- **Moderator Messages** will note what kind of moderator message was sent, and will include a link to the moderator message chain. These will be used for non-suspension moderator messages.
- **Suspensions** will do the same as moderator messages, but will additionally include the kind of suspension (what people see on the user's profile at the top) as well as the duration that the suspension was set for. These will be used when you suspend someone with a moderator message.

As a bonus to this feature, **we've fixed the annotation count on the user profile**. This number will now match up with the actual count of items in this top section - no more double-counts on suspensions or other oddities resulting from the old implementation. That number will now accurately tell you how many pieces of important information have been recorded in the history of that user.

All of these changes are retroactive, by the by, so all profiles should be up to date with the new style.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the count!  That always distracted me.